# vue3 vuex computed(() => store.state not show result

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Just wonder the computed(() => store.state work in this format?
I am getting
[image]

```
<script setup>
    import { useStore } from 'vuex';
    const store = useStore();
    const abc = computed(() => store.state['hello']);
        console.log(abc);
...

store.js
const store = createStore({
    state: {
        hello: 'hello123',
    },
```

Comment: Because abc is a ref.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution, need to do abc.value